# Calculate the Standard Deviation of Fundamental Frequency (MFCC)

Tags: speech-recognition, mfcc, statistics, fundamental-frequency

I'm implementing a gunshot detector following the article "[Algorithm for Gunshot Detection Using
Mel-Frequency Cepstrum Coefficients
(MFCC)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/269398905_Algorithm_for_Gunshot_Detection_Using_Mel-Frequency_Cepstrum_Coefficients_MFCC)" (paywall).

In the article, the authors uses 22 features based on MFCC (coeficients normalized between 0.1 and 0.9). One of the features is "Standard deviation of fundamental frequency". I already spent all my day trying to figure out the proper way to do this calculation.

The expected value for a gunshot is near 0.04.

Comment: So, where exactly does your problem lie? in the finding of the fundamental frequency, or in the finding of its variance?

Comment: The fundamental frequency.

Comment: I made some implementation using some formulas I found over the internet, but the results are very unrealistic compared to the expected.

Comment: Sadly, I don't have that paper. Can you maybe edit your question with a link to said paper? I'd assume the authors define how they *mean* fundamental frequency, and over which time window they want to determine it.

Comment: Done. That's why I'm suffering a lot, every paper has a lack of explaination some how. I always need to dig the information somewhere else, the big problem is on calculations that needs some kind of parameters that the authors generaly simply don't talk about.

Comment: thanks! Just from reading the abstract: I'll respectfully say that for something as easy to produce and reproduce as a gunshot, training a neural network with 80 samples is... a bit underwhelming.

Comment: I did notice that, but the results seems to be good, I mean, considering that they are reliable ...

Comment: They achieve 85% classification accuracy *within their own dataset*; that's not very good. Reference [9] they quote in their related works achieves 90% accuracy, and 96% in their own database. So, unless I'm misinterpreting the "related work" section, their results are worse than previous work by Smith.

Comment: You're right. But, back to the topic, do you have any clues of the standard deviation of fundamental frequency calculation? I concluded that the fundamental frequency can be obtained by calculating the greatest common divisor of the frequencies, but this results me a single number. How to apply the standard deviation on a single number? I must be missing something.

Comment: Sorry, no. and even if I had, it would be pure coincidence if that definition matches what the authors used but didn't define. So, really, that's a non-reproducible result. You'll have to ask the authors themselves or treat it as such.

Comment: I already tryied to contact them. No response so far. Thanx a lot for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

You calculate fundamental frequency of the signal with some pitch extraction algorithm, for example YIN, https://github.com/ronggong/pypYIN. It is a vector of numbers, then you calculate standard deviation of it, that would be a number.

Overall, this feature is not very important for detection. Also, the paper you are trying to reproduce is not quite modern, these days you can get much better results with VGGish and Audioset, something like

https://github.com/luuil/Tensorflow-Audio-Classification

or

https://github.com/IBM/MAX-Audio-Embedding-Generator